Why Django Admin static doesn't work in nginx and docker?
The problem is when I make docker-compose up and enter my website at localhost/admin in ngnix I don't see the default django admin styles.
nginx.conf
location /static/ {
  autoindex on;
  alias movies_admin/staticfiles/;
}

components/static.py
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'movies_admin/staticfiles/'

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8' 

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    
    volumes:
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin"
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin/staticfiles/"
    
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - DB_NAME=movies_database
      - DB_USER=app
      - DB_PASSWORD=123qwe
      - SECRET_KEY='django-insecure-8h%wg+drqmqjkw$8wm7#)#%*fb3b%(-e!-kbdth^#9u)23u!48'
    
    command:
      sh -c "uwsgi --ini /movies_admin/uwsgi.ini"
    
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  database:

    image: postgres:16

    environment:
      - DB_NAME=movies_database
      - DB_USER=app
      - DB_PASSWORD=123qwe
    
    volumes:
      - $HOME/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./movies_admin:/movies_admin/staticfiles/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev linux-headers pcre-dev

WORKDIR /movies_admin

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

EXPOSE 8000

COPY movies_admin .

RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input 

I read all available tutorials and understand the algorithm:

Setup staticfiles in settings.py
In Dockerfile collectstatic
Mount staticfile path in nginx and django containers volumes
Pass the path to the staticfiles in nginx.conf to setup routing if static was requested

Despite all this I don't see the styles in django admin. What might be the issue?
